# Using variables in Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I need use variable in select statement, but I don't know what I doing wrong.

If I run the **test** script bellow, it's works fine:

```
DECLARE 
    SalesOrderId VARCHAR(10);
BEGIN
    SalesOrderId := '138296584';

    dbms_output.put_line(SalesOrderId);
END;
```

But, if I put a select query inside Begin-End block, don't work. Here the code:

```
DECLARE 
    SalesOrderId VARCHAR(10);
BEGIN
    SalesOrderId := '138296584';

    dbms_output.put_line(SalesOrderId);

    SELECT * FROM tblOrders tbl WHERE tbl.SalesOrderId = SalesOrderId; 
END;
```

And throws the error:

```
[Error] Execution (8: 5): ORA-06550: line 8, column 5: PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

What I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: An anonymous PL/SQL block cannot return table data. You could either write a PL/SQL function that does this (a pipelined function) or have your block put out the data on the console (DBMS_OUTPUT) or use SQL with bind variables (`WHERE tbl.SalesOrderId = :SalesOrderId;`).

Answer (score 0):

There error is clear, you need to store the output somewhere (make sense) , so use the `INTO` :

```
SELECT tbl.SalesOrderId,tbl.column1
INTO varSalesOrderId,varColumn1
FROM tblOrders tbl 
WHERE tbl.SalesOrderId = SalesOrderId;
```

Comment: For real my query do some left joins and I select column from these tables, so I don't have a simple data in select and the Into don't work. Error: [Error] Execution (16: 5): ORA-06550: line 16, column 5:
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
ORA-06550: line 8, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: @JoseFelipeBlumdeAraujo You can use `INTO` with multiple variables.. see edit .

Comment: Ok, now I do the right thing, I put all columns which I'm using, but other error throws: [Error] Execution (1: 3): ORA-01843: not a valid month ORA-06512: at line 15 The line error is in: SalesOrderId := 138296584